# Segmentation Fault(core dump)

Tags: c, unix

I am getting Segmentation error(core dump) in the following code:

```
void Update_Log( )
{
        struct logData update;
        int file;

        char *writeBuffer=NULL;

        if((file=creat("/home/user/Desktop/DMS/DMS/filename.txt",O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY))==-1)
                perror("file not opened");
        update.clientName="user";
        update.filename="user";
        update.timestamp="some time";
        sprintf(writeBuffer,"%s %s %s",update.clientName,update.filename,update.timestamp);


        if((write(file,writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer)))==-1)
                perror("write unsuccessful");
        close(file);
}
```

My structure is as follows:

```
struct logData
{
        char *clientName;
        char *filename;
        char *timestamp;
};
```

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a crash, segmentation fault or other, is to run your program in a debugger. It will help you find the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused it.

Comment: hmmm thanks for the input. I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to write to `writeBuffer` which is a null pointer, you should declare it as array(1), or allocate a memory on the heap(2) for it.

1. `char writeBuffer[100];`
2. `char *writeBuffer=malloc(100)`

in both cases you should not use `sprintf`, but `snprintf` to make sure you are not overflowing your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

When 'update' is created it only allocates the space for the pointers of the strings clientName, filename, timestamp; it does not allocate space for the string itself.  A quick hack would be to do something like update.clientName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len) where len is the length of what you want to allocate.  Then you should really check the return code of that call...

This is exactly the same issue as with the write buffer... you just need to make sure you allocate space for all your strings.

Comment: This is true, but not the reason for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The error is these two lines:

```
char *writeBuffer=NULL;

/* ... */

sprintf(writeBuffer, /* ... */);
```

Here you write into a `NULL` pointer.

Create an array instead, e.g.

```
char writeBuffer[32];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for writeBuffer.

You could use malloc, or if you have limits on the size of the data (eg if it will be less than 256 bytes) just declare it as

```
char writeBuffer[256];
```

I'd also recommend looking up and using snprintf instead of sprintf to make sure data doesnt run off the end.

Answer (score 0):

your struct store only *pointers*, no memory is allocated for the actual data.
Either you should have

```
struct logData
{
        char clientName[SOMEDEFINE1NUMBERHERE];
        char filename[SOMEDEFINE2NUMBERHERE];
        char timestamp[SOMEDEFINE3NUMBERHERE];
};
```

or you allocate the memory (`malloc`)

update.clientname = (char *)malloc(SOMEDEFINE1NUMBERHERE);
   strncpy(update.clientname, "user");

Answer (score 0):

As Binyamin Sharet wrote `sprintf` is not allocating the output buffer. The caller must provide an output buffer that is *long enough*. This is not always simple. Therefor I advise you to use `fopen` instead of `open`. Then you can code like that:

```
void Update_Log( )  
{  
        struct logData update;  
        FILE *file = fopen("/home/user/Desktop/DMS/DMS/filename.txt", "w");  

        if(file==NULL) {  
                perror("file not opened");  
                return;
        }
        update.clientName="user";  
        update.filename="user";  
        update.timestamp="some time";  
        if(fprintf(file,"%s %s %s",update.clientName,update.filename,update.timestamp) < 0)  
                perror("write unsuccessful");  
        fclose(file);
```

}

As you can see the code is shorter and it has no potential buffer overflow.

Answer (score -1):

It crashes, because `writeBuffer` is `NULL`.

You need to allocate memory for `writeBuffer` using malloc - use `strlen` (for example) to calculate the neccesary space (don't forget `\0` and the spaces in the `sprintf`).

OR, you may allocate some fixed size array automatically:

```
char writeBuffer[ SOME_SIZE_BIG_ENOUGH ];
```

---

Also, you should not do this:

```
    update.clientName="user";
    update.filename="user";
    update.timestamp="some time";
```

You have several options:

- use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/)
- use `strdup` (POSSIX)
- make the pointers `const char*`, not just `char*`.